# I can't install Pygame Zero or Pygame library

Tags: windows-10, python

I am using Windows 10 and have version 3.9.2 of Python. I tried using the command: `pip install pygame`
and trying the command: `pip install pgzero`

I get the following message back at the Command prompt:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pygame/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pygame/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually downloading the wheel file and installing it using pip? While it doesn't solve the underlying problem it might be good enough for now.

1. Go to https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files and find the version you need, from your description it would be "pygame-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl" for cp3.9.
2. Open Powershell or cmd, navigate to your Downloads folder and run `pip install pygame-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` or other appropriate version.

This worked for me no problem. You can do the same for the other package, just find its pypi page.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121246/discussion-on-answer-by-olaf-sikorski-i-cant-install-pygame-zero-or-pygame-libr).

Answer (score 0):

This sometime happen if your “pip” is out of date
and the package you are installing is not exist in the current version of “pip”

Try writing this in command prompt:

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

but also it says that “pip” could not verify the SSL certificate
so if you’ve updated “pip” and it didn’t work then try to update openssl.

honestly I don’t know how to do this on Windows
but it’s more likely that this problem will be fixed if you update “pip” only